# Create radio buttons in React

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, components

so i have these 4 divs:

How can I change these normal divs to act like radio buttons? I want, when I press on one of them, to act like a radio button and do something, like change the color of the border.

Here is the code:

```
<div className="rcorners2 blue-border"><img src = {clinic} alt="Heart Logo" className="logo"/>
      <div className="div1-number">
        <b>4</b>
      </div>
      <div className="div1-string">
        All Studies
      </div>
      </div>
      <div className="rcorners2" ><img src = {medkit} alt="Heart Logo" className="logo"/>
      <div className="div2-number">
      <b>4</b>
      </div>
      <div  className="div2-string">
        Active Studies
      </div>
      </div>
      <div className="rcorners2"><img src = {alert} alt="Heart Logo" className="logo">
        </img>
        <div className="div3-number">
        <b>4</b>
        </div>
        <div  className="div3-string">
          Urgent
        </div>
        </div>
      <div className="rcorners2" ><img src = {watch} alt="Heart Logo" className="logo">
        </img>
        <div className="div4-number">
        <b>4</b>
        </div>
        <div  className="div4-string">
          Behind Schedule
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: this is the css code:
.rcorners2 {
    
border-radius: 25px;
    
background-color: white;
    
padding: 20px;
    
margin-top: 5%;
    
display: inline-block;
    
margin-left: 2%; 
    
width: 320px;
    
height: 90px;
    
box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.161);  
  }

.logo { 
    
float:left;

width: 20%;
    
height:100%;
    
border-radius: 20%;
}

Comment: Add onClick to the div like <div className="div1-string" onCLick={this.handleOnCLick}>

Comment: @SulungNugroho i understood good idea but if i set onClick on all the divs and pressed on all of them one at a time they will all be colored in blue.what i want is one at a time for example if i pressed on the first one then the second, the second will be colored and the first will be turned off

Comment: You can user ref. or put different value on each div like onClick={ () => this.handleOnClick(1)). Then you can filter  the method handleOnClick = (val) => {  if(val === 1) { do something.....}  }

Answer (score 0):

You can learn from this code to solve your case. This is only an approach as reference only.

Note : You need a new class name for the toggle class other than default class name.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class SampleClass extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.elementDiv1 = React.createRef();
    this.elementDiv2 = React.createRef();
    this.elementDiv3 = React.createRef();

 }

  handleOnClick = (val) => {

    if(val === 1) {

        let elmDiv1 = this.elementDiv1.current;     
        elmDiv1.classList.toggle("text-danger"); // suppose using bootstrap

    }else if(val === 2) {

        let elmDiv2 = this.elementDiv2.current;     
        elmDiv2.classList.toggle("text-primary");

    }else if(val === 3) {

        let elmDiv3 = this.elementDiv3.current;     
        elmDiv3.classList.toggle("text-warning");

    }
  }


  render() {   
    return (
       <div>           
        <div className="div1-string" ref={this.elementDiv1} onClick={()=>this.handleOnClick(1)}>
        All Studies
        </div>      
         <div className="div2-string" ref={this.elementDiv2} onClick={()=>this.handleOnClick(2)}>
        Active Studies
        </div>      
         <div className="div3-string" ref={this.elementDiv3} onClick={()=>this.handleOnClick(3)}>
           Urgent
        </div>               
       </div>
    )
  }
}
```

See the React documentation using React.createRef().